# How to handle JWT Authentication with Spring when implementing a CQRS pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, cqrs

Using the latest Spring Cloud and Spring Boot, I've got a micro services layout with a Zuul gateway. At the moment when a user sends a get request their JWT token gets added to the request and that goes off to the microservice where they're authenticated and things go as usual. This all works perfectly.

Where I'm a little stuck is when handling POST/PATCH/DELETE requests. These don't go directly to the microservice they're destined for, but instead go into a messaging queue. The queue contains a simple POJO with a task and information about the task to perform, along with the users JWT.

When the receiving microservice picks up the message from the queue and starts processing it, the user isn't technically logged into the microservice like they are with a GET request. This makes it hard to do things that require knowing who the user is. Sure each time I need to know who the person is I can look them up, but that seems clunky.

I've thought about creating a REST controller for the POST/PATCH/DELETE commands and having the queue listener just call itself from these, adding the token from the task. This would effectively be the same as a GET request as far as Spring security would care.

Is this the proper pattern? Or is there a simple programmatically way to log a user in with a JWT? I've seen a few examples using Username/Passwords but not sure how to transcribe that to using a JWT.

Comment: I actually like your solution to call yourself. It's elegant and gives your service async and sync abilities. There are other ways to do async but given you already have a queueing infra to work with this is a nice way to wire it into a REST controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Andy Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763035/andy-brown) for the confirmation I wasn't completely nuts doing it this way. For anyone interested it's a very simple solution that looks like this:

The queue service is just listening for events (In this case from AWS SQS) and as soon as an event comes through it gets fired off to a command controller for processing.

```
@Service
@EnableSqs
public class QueueListener {

    private final static String SERVICE = "http://instance-service/instances";

    @Autowired
    private JsonTransformService jsonTransformService;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("${queues.instanceEvents}")
    public void instanceCommandHandler(String payload) {

        // Transform the payload to the object so we can get the preset JWT
        Instance instance = jsonTransformService.read(Instance.class, payload);

        // Load the JWT into the internal request header, without this a 403 is thrown
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + instance.getUserToken());
        HttpEntity<String> instanceEntity = new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers);

        // Decide and set where to fire the request to
        String endpoint;
        switch (instance.getSwordfishCommand()) {
            case "start": {
                endpoint = "/start";
                break;
            }
            case "stop": {
                endpoint = "/stop";
                break;
            }
            case "create": {
                endpoint = "/create";
                break;
            }
            case "reboot": {
                endpoint = "/reboot";
                break;
            }
            case "terminate": {
                endpoint = "/terminate";
                break;
            }
            default: {
                endpoint = "/error";
            }
        }

        // Fire the initial string payload through to the correct controller endpoint
        restTemplate.exchange(SERVICE + endpoint, HttpMethod.POST, instanceEntity, String.class);
    }
}
```

And a very simple REST controller which actions the tasks

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/instances")
public class InstanceCommandController {

    @Autowired
    private EC2Create ec2Create;

    @Autowired
    private EC2Start ec2Start;

    @Autowired
    private EC2Stop ec2Stop;

    @Autowired
    private EC2Reboot ec2Reboot;

    @Autowired
    private EC2Terminate ec2Terminate;

    @Autowired
    private JsonTransformService jsonTransformService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public void create(@RequestBody String payload) {
        ec2Create.process(jsonTransformService.read(Instance.class, payload));
    }

    @PostMapping("/start")
    public void start(@RequestBody String payload) {
        ec2Start.process(jsonTransformService.read(Instance.class, payload));
    }

    @PostMapping("/stop")
    public void stop(@RequestBody String payload) {
        ec2Stop.process(jsonTransformService.read(Instance.class, payload));
    }

    @PostMapping("/reboot")
    public void reboot(@RequestBody String payload) {
        ec2Reboot.process(jsonTransformService.read(Instance.class, payload));
    }

    @PostMapping("/terminate")
    public void terminate(@RequestBody String payload) {
        ec2Terminate.process(jsonTransformService.read(Instance.class, payload));
    }
}
```

This follows the CQRS pattern very well while still authenticating the user on each call. For me this is very useful as I have a `AmazonEC2Async` client which makes use of the users own access and secret token in each request.

Cheers for the help!